# why val_loss and val_accuracy not showing in epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to classify images whether they're cats,dogs or pandas. the data contains all of images (cats + dogs + pandas) and the labels contains the labels of them but somehow when i fit the data to the model, the `val_loss` and `val_accuracy` does not show up, the only metrics shown in each epochs are `loss` and `accuracy`. I have no clue why it's not showing up but i have feeling that it's because i don't pass `validation_data` so i passed `X_test.all()` into `validation_data` but the `val_loss` and `val_accuracy` still does not show up, what should i do?

```
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2,2), activation = 'relu', input_shape= (height, width, n_channels)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(2,2), activation= 'relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(2,2), activation= 'relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256,(2,2), activation= 'relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation= 'relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation= 'softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 3)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=25, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to input validation test in your model fit.

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=25, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test,y_test))

Comment: this doesn't work, it returns `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible`

Comment: It means that the shape is incorrect. Could your send X_train.shape, y_train.shape,X_test.shape and y_test.shape.

Comment: X_train is (2400, 32, 55, 3), X_test is (600, 32, 55, 3),y_train is (2400, 3),y_test is (600,)

Comment: There is a difference in the dimensions of the data for y_train and y_test. Thats the problem. y_train has 3 columns and y_test hast 1 column so data is missing. If its categorical then convert it to one hot by.  
you forget to convert y_test variable to categorical type. Add this line,

y_test  = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test  , 3)

Answer (score 1):

you forget to convert y_test  variable to categorical type. Add this line,

```
y_test  = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test  , 3)
```